# ASObjc Runner shellscript progress

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make a progress bar using ASObjC Runner.
The progress bar has to show the progress of a shell script, in this case "sleep 5". I came up with this script:

```
    repeat with i from 1 to 100
    do shell script "sleep 5"
    tell application "ASObjC Runner"
        reset progress
        activate
        show progress
        set properties of progress window to {detail:"Progress: " & i, current value:i}
        if button was pressed of progress window then
            exit repeat
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
tell application "ASObjC Runner" to quit
```

But his script only updates the progress bar by 1% if the shell script is finished, so it takes 5 seconds to get 1% progress.
Is it possible to get this working, so the progress bar is 100% after the shell script completes.
Help appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the progress bar while the shell script is running, I'm afraid this is not possible. Shell scripts in AppleScript run synchronously, your code does this (step by step)

- script starts
- script waits 5 seconds
- script begins to talk to ASObjC Runner

Comment: You can make a shell script run asynchronously by using the syntax `set PID to do shell script "sleep 5 &> /dev/null & echo $!"`. The nice thing about this is it will also return the PID of the process just backgrounded, so you can use it for whatever you want. With a more advanced shell script, you could implement some communication between this backgrounded process and the calling AppleScript.